# Getting images from system Gallery. Why is not working?

Tags: android

I made a program where user show which picture he want to load in this app. When user want to load picture, he can choose what kind of file explorer he want to use:

[image]

Everything works, but if I choose "Gallery" and  mark my image, it doesn't work. It happens only when i choose "Gallery".

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                 String path = data.getData().getPath();
                 try {
        loadedimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sciezka_z_obrazem);
          }
                  catch (Exception e) {
                   }
            } [...]
```

After picking image from Gallery, loadedimage is null.
When I use Dropbox or "My Files" everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use

```
Uri mUri = data.getData();
```

In case of Gallery the file returned is of the form content:// rather than file://

So you should use the uri rather than doing getPath on uri

Edit:
Use uri to decode like below

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

loadedimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is)
```

Comment: but If I using decodeFile to load image I must after all use String. So what's the difference when I use Uri instead String?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.
        File filePath= new File(path);
and then use
        Uri.fromFile(filePath)
this would set the content wchich could be openend.